# How can I evaluate on-chip bypass-capacitor's capacity based on the topology?

Tags: power-supply, integrated-circuit, layout, bypass-capacitor

The transmitter I designed has been showing lots of jitter.I think there's something wrong with the layout topology.Pad of the power supply is a little far away from the circuits by connection through thin metals,thus producing a resistance as large as 2 ohms,which would lead to IR-Drop.It will not do much harm if bypass-capacitor for the power is large enough to compensate for that.But I feel since the mesh-structure capacitor(green part in the pic) mostly sprawls over the chip distant from the current path, its capacity on providing the transients must have been weakened than if it is "properly" placed.I really want to know if it can be turned to some actual,smaller-value one so I can see its effect through simulation on Spectre?

Also:It seems to me that the inductance is large because of the loop,but how can I estimate it?
[image]

Comment: what type of capacitor construction is it?  PIP, MIM, etc.

Comment: @degnan it's MIM.

Comment: Are you simulating the jitter as absolute noise on the output?  Given some time, you should split the capacitor into several and place them closer to the circuits that suspect to be noisy.  I have MIM caps and depletion caps.  I have the MIMs over the items as it's a faster path and then have the depletion caps for a charge pool.  I am sorry to say that I do not have any ideas without digging into the design.